# Why does jest consider whole functions as "not covered branches" when reporting test coverage?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

I am working on a CRA repo and I am adding tests.

I am facing the issue that Jest reports whole functions as not covered branches; functions that have otherwise no branching logic at all.

e.g.

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

function useToggleModal(initialState = false) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(initialState);

  const handleOpenModal = useCallback(() => setIsOpen(true), []);
  const handleCloseModal = useCallback(() => setIsOpen(false), []);

  return { isOpen, handleOpenModal, handleCloseModal };
}

export default useToggleModal;
```

This is a straightforward function, yet, while every other test metric for it is at 100%, branch coverage sits at 0%, reporting line 3 (the start of the function declaration) as the uncovered branch, which makes no sense.

I have many other such cases among my tests and this behaviour is tanking my branch coverage % for no apparent reason.

Changing the `coverageProvider` option to `v8` instead of `babel` seems to generate correct reports, at least for such cases which I know are reported wrong when using `babel` as a coverage provider. I am hesitant as to whether I should keep `v8` though since [there are some issues with it](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11188)

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coverageprovider-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out the function accepting an optional argument, with a default value, *is* considered a branch, so I needed to have a test that does not pass an argument. Seems so obvious in hindsight.